# how to create static resources for jqyeryui

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

Hi i have some problem in the static resources using in jqueryui in visual force,
dowmloaded jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.zip , and stored in static resources page , but unfortunely the ui is not working , if anyone guide me how to use static resources

ganesz

Comment: Can you show us the code you use in the VF page?

Comment: How do you know "it is not working", what is the message you get ? Adding more details in your question will help us analyse where it's going wrong. Besides that, asking a question multiple times will also not help much.

Comment: but using url its working , im using static resources its not working , for e.g my static resources name is - jquery , file type - jquery-custoom-1.10.3.zip file

Answer (score 2):

If you upload a zip file you should use URLFOR function like this

```
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQuerUI,'jquery-ui-1.10.3.js')}"/>

<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.YourResourceName,'path_to_file_inside_your_zip')}"/>
```

Comment: JqueryUI is the objectname of static resources

Comment: Yes. e.g. if it was a simple file (js not zip) you could just write src="{!$Resource.JQueyUI}"

Comment: but its not working moti korets